# Subquery returns NULL in "NOT IN"

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Here is my query

```
select distinct(Challan_No) 
from  Challan_tb 
where Challan_No not in 
  (
    select Challan_No from Invoice_tb where Customer_ID =2 and InvYear=2013
  ) and InvYear=2013 and Customer_ID =2
```

the subquery is returning `NULL` so the outer query is not working

Please help

Comment: So you are trying to get distinct Challan_No where there is no invoice? Try giving your sub query an alias. `select Challan_No from Invoice_tb I where I.Customer_ID =2 and I.InvYear=2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple, obvious fix, if you don't want to change the structure of the query too much:

```sql
select distinct(Challan_No) 
from  Challan_tb 
where Challan_No not in 
  (
    select Challan_No from Invoice_tb where Customer_ID =2 and InvYear=2013
    and Challan_No is not null --This line is new
  ) and InvYear=2013 and Customer_ID =2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a LEFT JOIN instead. I think Access will digest this better.

```
select distinct(Challan_tb.Challan_No) 
from Challan_tb 
left join Invoice_tb on Invoice_tb.Challan_No = Challan_tb.Challan_No
where Challan_tb.InvYear=2013 and Challan_tb.Customer_ID=2
and Invoice_tb.InvYear is null --or any other Invoice_tb field
```

Comment: You forgot the `AND Invoice_tb.Customer_ID =2 and Invoice_tb.InvYear=2013` (it should be at the `ON` clause.)

Comment: I was assuming that Challan_No was a unique identifier connecting the two, rendering Customer_ID and InvYear unnecessary in the ON clause, but still used in the WHERE clause.